# Как изменять шрифт в textview во всем приложении

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Есть ползунок, через который нужно реализовать смену шрифта во всех textview приложения. Как это реализовать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно реализовать так.

1. Создайте класс для хранения ваших шрифтов (список шрифтов можно посмотреть тут [fonts](http://iosfonts.com)).
2. В созданном классе, создайте статическую коллекцию в параметрами [имя_шрифта: шрифт]

Пример

```
struct StaticFonsts {
  static var fontsDict = [
    "AlNile-Bold"                        : UIFont(name: "AlNile-Bold", size: 12),
    "AmericanTypewriter-CondensedLight"  : UIFont(name: "AmericanTypewriter-CondensedLight", size: 12),
    "AppleColorEmoji"                    : UIFont(name: "AppleColorEmoji", size: 12),
    "AppleSDGothicNeo-Light "            : UIFont(name: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Light ", size: 12),
    "Arial"                              : UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 12),
    "Avenir-Black"                       : UIFont(name: "Avenir-Black", size: 12),
  ]
}
```

3. Пропишите в вашем слайдере мин и макс значения

Пример

```
slider.minimumValue = 0   
slider.maximumValue = Float(StaticFonsts.fontsDict.count - 1)
```

4. Последнее что необходимо сделать это округлять значения слайдера и прописывать значения в textView.

Пример

```
  @IBAction func changeFont(_ sender: UISlider) {
    let value = Int(sender.value)
    let key = Array(StaticFonsts.fontsDict.keys)[value]
    print(key)
    let font = StaticFonsts.fontsDict[key]
    guard let tempFont = font else {
      print("error font")
      return
    }
    textView.font = tempFont
  }
```

Если вам необходимо менять на нескольких `UIViewController` то можно создать синглтон с параметром currentFont, и при изменении шрифта на слайдере, записывать туда этот шрифт.

А при создании новых `UIViewController` в методе `viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)` загружать нужный шрифт из синглтона.

Пример

Создание

```
final class CurrentFont {
  private init() {}
  static let shared = CurrentFont()
  var currentFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
}
```

Запись

```
CurrentFont.shared.currentFont = tempFont
```

Чтение

```
textView.font = CurrentFont.shared.currentFont
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное